# Exponentiation function intel assembly

Tags: assembly, bison, yacc, exponentiation

Using bison to generate assembly code for a simple calculator, but I can't figure out exactly what my bug is here, all the answers seem to be one multiplication off...

```
global intpow
intpow:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    mov     ecx,[ebp+8]
    mov     eax,[ebp+12]

loop:
    cmp     eax,1
    jle     finish
    dec     eax
    imul    ecx,ecx
    jmp     loop

finish:
    mov     eax,ecx
    mov     esp,ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Here's the code in my .y file when I identify an exponent call:

```
exp '^' exp        { $$ = pow ($1, $3);
          printf("call\tintpow\n");
          printf("push\tDWORD eax\n");
}
```

Is the assembly wrong? The .y? Both?

Comment: I suggest you employ rubber duck debugging and comment each line of assembly with what you believe it is doing.

Comment: `imul ecx, ecx` will overwrite the original value with the multiplied result. The second iteration of the loop will compute `(y * y) * (y * y)` instead of `(y * y) * y`, and so on.

Comment: Instead of a power function you've written [a tetration function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), which is same as [Knuth's double-arrow function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation). It's valid code, only for different purpose.

Comment: What you are calculating is x^(2^y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([Comments converted to an Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@DCoder wrote:

> `imul ecx, ecx` will overwrite the original value with the multiplied result. The second iteration of the loop will compute `(y * y) * (y * y)` instead of `(y * y) * y`, and so on.

@nrz wrote:

> nstead of a power function you've written a tetration function, which is same as Knuth's double-arrow function. It's valid code, only for different purpose.

@hirschhornsalz wrote:

> What you are calculating is x^(2^y).